# Add an image to iText pdf in Android

Tags: android, image, itext, spannable, itextg

I have an String containing images like "My string [img src=image_from_drawable/] blablabla". I'm able to parse this string as Spannable to show that drawable on my TextView, with the following code:

```
static public Spannable formatAbility(String _ability) {
    Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(_ability);
    addImages(mContext, spannable);
    return spannable;
}

private static boolean addImages(Context context, Spannable spannable) {
    Pattern refImg = Pattern
            .compile("\\Q[img src=\\E([a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)\\Q/]\\E");
    boolean hasChanges = false;

    Matcher matcher = refImg.matcher(spannable);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        boolean set = true;
        for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(),
                matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class)) {
            if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                    && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end()) {
                spannable.removeSpan(span);
            } else {
                set = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        String resname = spannable
                .subSequence(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1)).toString()
                .trim();
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resname, "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());

        if (set) {
            hasChanges = true;

            spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, id,
                    ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), matcher.start(), matcher
                    .end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

    return hasChanges;
}
```

I'm using iText/iTextG library for my Android project in order to create a pdf file.

**My question is**: Is there an easy way to do this in iText? Write a Phrase or Paragraph containing images? I presume that Chunks would help, but I don't find the way, examples or anything else.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a `Chunk` with an image is indeed the way to go. Please take a look at this chapter of the ZUGFeRD tutorial: [Creating PDF/A files with iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/2-creating-pdfa-files-itext)

It has an example that creates text with images that look like this:

[image]

This is how it's done:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Chunk c = new Chunk("The quick brown ");
p.add(c);
Image i = Image.getInstance("resources/images/fox.bmp"");
c = new Chunk(i, 0, -24);
p.add(c);
c = new Chunk(" jumps over the lazy ");
p.add(c);
i = Image.getInstance("resources/images/dog.bmp"");
c = new Chunk(i, 0, -24);
p.add(c);
document.add(p);
```

I hope this helps.